# Count how many metrics matches a condition in graphite

Tags: monitoring, graphite

I have a list of classes that extracts info from the web. Every time each one of them saves something, it sends a different counter to graphite. So, every one of them is a different metric.

How do I know how many of them satisfy a certain condition??

For example, let:

```
movingAverage(summarize(groupByNode(counters.crawlers.*.saved, 2, "sumSeries), "1hour"), 24)
```

be the average of content download in past 24 hours. How can i know, at a moment "t", how many of my metrics have this value above 0?

Answer (score 1):

In the rendering endpoint, add `format=json`. This would return the data-points with corresponding epochs in JSON, which is a breeze to parse. The time-stamps wherein your script sent nothing will be NULL.

```
[{
 "target": "carbon.agents.ip-10-0-0-228-a.metricsReceived",
 "datapoints": 
  [
    [912, 1383888170], 
    [789, 1383888180], 
    [800, 1383888190], 
    [null, 1383888200], 
    [503, 1383888210], 
    [899, 1383888220]
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Thnx @erbdex. That's one way to count it. It is better than what i have right now. I guess i didn't made myself clear. I want to represent this in a graphite graph.

Comment: The DIY approach would be to write a simple script that calculates whatever you need and sends it back to statsd to chart a graph again (of graph-metadata). Nothing like the flexibility of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `currentAbove` function.  [Check it out](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.currentAbove).  For example:

```
currentAbove(stats.route.*.servertime.*, 5)
```

The above example gets all of the metrics (in the series) that are above 5.

---

You could then count the number of targets returned, and while Graphite doesn't provide a way to count the "buckets" you should be able to capture it fairly easily.

For example, a way to get a quick count (using curl to pipe to grep and count on the word "target"). Like so:

```
> curl -silent http://test.net/render?target=currentAbove(stats.cronica.dragnet.messages.*, 5)&format=json \
> | grep -Po "target" | grep -c "target"
```

Comment: countSeries(*seriesLists) draws a horizontal line representing the number of nodes found in the seriesList. It is available from v0.9.10 onward. But i don't think that he wants to know how many wildcards got resolved.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about that function. In that case, a combo of currentAbove(around his original movingAverage etc) using 0 (to get metrics above 0), wrapped with countSeries would do the same as the script.  Although perhaps I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: i guess he wants the flexibility of programming custom checks when he says "satisfy a certain condition". :) But yeah, don't really know.